# Django says ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf does not appear to have any patterns in it

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and I'm facing a problem with a repo I downloaded. I've looked at other answers, but they don't seem to apply to my project, or I don't have the same errors some have. It sends the error

```
File "C:\Users\Iván\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 596, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'quiniela.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

My quiniela.urls looks like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from quinewhats.views import Home
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView
from django.urls import include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', Home.as_view()),
    path("logout/", LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
    path('liga/',include('liga.urls',namespace='liga')),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And my liga.urls like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import EquiposTableView,EquiposCreateView,EquiposUpdateView,EquiposDeleteView, LigaTableView, LigaCreateView, LigaUpdateView, LigaDeleteView, TorneosTableView,TorneosCreateView,TorneosDeleteView,TorneosUpdateView

app_name='liga'

urlpatterns = [
    path('equipos/table/', EquiposTableView.as_view(), name='tabla_equipos'),
    path('equipos/create/',EquiposCreateView.as_view(), name='crear_equipos'),
    path('equipos/update/<int:pk>/',EquiposUpdateView.as_view(), name='actualizar_equipos'),
    path('equipos/delete/<int:pk>/',EquiposDeleteView.as_view(), name='eliminar_equipos'),
    path('liga/table/', LigaTableView.as_view(), name='tabla_liga'),
    path('liga/create/', LigaCreateView.as_view(), name='crear_liga'),
    path('liga/update/<int:pk>/', LigaUpdateView.as_view(), name='actualizar_liga'),
    path('liga/delete/<int:pk>/', LigaDeleteView.as_view(), name='eliminar_liga'),

]
```

I don't know what a circular import is, but I read it could be that my urls.py was somewhat imported to a views.py, but I checked and it doesn't seem to be the case. Is there any other thing I'm overseeing, or some other information that could be useful? This has taken me longer than I hoped.

**EDIT:**
This are the INSTALLED_APPS:

[image]

And this is the file structure:

[image]

Comment: Can you show the file structure of your app and the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting?

Comment: Your url files seem ok as far as I can tell so the issue is either with a circular import or something else failing to import

Comment: The first thing I'd try would be to comment out the references to quinewhat.views. If it still doesn't work. comment out the include of liga.urls

Comment: I updated the post with the INSTALLED_APPS and the file structure.

Comment: I commented the reference to quinewhats.views in quiniela/urls.py, and have the same error, is that the one you meant?

Comment: Ok, commenting the liga.urls line seemed to stop the error when starting the server, but then it sends me that 'liga' is not a registered namespace, which makes sense, but I think this is closer to what's wrong.

Could it be that "liga" is the name of an app (which is why it's included in 'quiniela.urls'), but also the name of a model, which is why it's included in 'liga.urls'? I don't see overlapping in the url patterns, but I don't know if it could be something related to that.

Comment: No check what's being imported in liga/views.py (or show us).

Comment: circular imports are basically two modules trying to import each other, but the "circle" can actually include quite a few other modules, ie A imports B imports C imports D imports E imports A. And this can be further complicated by dynamic imports, such as those performed by django at process startup to initialize all apps / models etc from the INSTALLED_APPS. In all cases your issue comes from a failed import (whatever the reason - circular import, plain typo or else) , either of liga.views itself or something imported by it.

Comment: You should check `quinewhats.views` and see if it is not directly or indirectly importing `quiniela.urls`

Answer (score 0):

do not mention parenthesis to the view method
ex :- EquiposCreateView.as_view() ----> EquiposCreateView.as_view

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Go to your **project folder url**, there check your **urlpatterns**. Maybe you have forgotten to type like this,

```
urlpatterns = [
path("", include("your_app.urls")),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using reverse_lazy instead of reverse is indeed a good approach, especially in class-based views where you need to delay the URL reversing process until it's actually needed. This helps avoid potential circular import issues that can occur when using reverse directly.

Here's the modified line in your view code:
change

```
success_url = reverse('')
```

to

```
success_url = reverse_lazy('')
```

Using reverse_lazy ensures that the URL is only evaluated when needed, which can help prevent import-related errors during the project's initialization.